# Can mongodb run without initiating it?

Tags: mongodb

```js
const dbConnect = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/zWebApp';
mongoose
  .connect(dbConnect, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Successfull!`);
  });
```

When I connect my **nodeJs** web application with local **mongodb** database,
It just works fine without initiating it in the cmd
..like mongod.exe My question was the above code runs without any operational errors, but I didn't start the server manually, the tutorial I have been watching says first start the server from the command line, then connect it. if it helps with hope..is it logically correct?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're looking for, but if you make a singleton function to connect to mongo and check connection it helps to maintain single instance and also restarts whenever mongo connection is down.

Comment: please make question clear

Answer (score 0):

`Mongod` runs as a background service generally on windows startup (unless disabled). That's why you don't need to start anything but if connection error occurs that might be the first place to look as something might have interrupted the launch of the service, then you need to manually start it.